# jQuery jTable edit and add popup divs Save button on enter press

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-jtable

when i edit or add new post to jQuery jTable, i want that when i am done and press enter jquery click Save button!

i am trying something like this, but it is not working!

```
$("#jtable-create-form > div > div > input").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
       $("#AddRecordDialogSaveButton").click();
    }
});
```

The html stucture is something like this:

```
<div id="jtable-create-form"> // poput div
  <div> //form wraper div
     <div> //input wraper div
        <input>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when i try to just alert `$("#jtable-create-form > div > div > input").val()` i get `undefined`!

Anyone have tried this, or maybe sees the solution!?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#jtable-create-form input").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
       $("#AddRecordDialogSaveButton").trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this, and it does not work eather, i tried this code on document.ready
    $(".jtable-toolbar-item-add-record").click(function(){
         console.log($("#jtable-edit-form").find("input").val());
    });
but all i get is `undefined` again! i think problem is there, i junst dont know how to solve it!

Comment: Can you show full HTML code? I can't see in HTML `#AddRecordDialogSaveButton`. http://jsfiddle.net/phpowl/F3chc/

Comment: i can't show you the HTML, because table and popup div is generated and created by jQuery jTable plugin. I guess what i am really asking how to override the Save Button

Answer (score 0):

I found the following seems to work:

```
$('#tablediv').jtable('load', {}, function(data) {

    $(document).on('keydown', '#jtable-create-form input', function(ev) {
        if(ev.which === 13) {
            $("#AddRecordDialogSaveButton").trigger('click');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('keydown', '#jtable-edit-form input', function(ev) {
        if(ev.which === 13) {
            $("#EditDialogSaveButton").trigger('click');
        }
    });

});//end load form
```

(but *not* for parent>child tables).

**Explanation:**

I specify a callback function (post table load) which ensures that the edit and create dialogs exist before wiring the keydown handlers to them.

I then attach a keydown handler only if the focus is in an input that is a child of the appropriate form.

Note that I'm attaching two handlers, one to the create form and one to the edit form, and that I'm specifically looking out for key code 13 which is the ENTER key.

The only problem, as mentioned above, seems to be that if you have parent>child jtables the enter key press seems to trigger a create/update for BOTH a null parent AND a child which is totally unacceptable... but if you only have single level jtables this code should work.

(Only Tested in chrome)